# Focus on keypress, blur on specific key press

Tags: jquery

I have an input field that is focused the instant I start typing. I want to blur (un-focus?) the input field when I press enter.

Edit: [Fixed & working thanks to smerny, here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/og41Lnvv/3/)

```
    $('body').on('keydown', function() {
        var input = $('input[name="textfield"]');

        if(!input.is(':focus')) {
            input.focus();
        }
    });

    $('#keyboard_input').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 13){
            callajax();
            $(this).blur();    
        }
    });
```

My current problem is that the enter key also then refocuses the input field due to the keydown function.

What would be the best way to make the enter key work sort of like a toggle switch?

Comment: well, there is no `#keyboard_input` element, perhaps you meant `#textfield`?  http://jsfiddle.net/og41Lnvv/2/

Comment: I miss typed the element id in the fiddle, sorry. The problem ended up being the callajax();, you fixed it by commenting it out. So thank you!

Comment: Commented it out because it's not defined in the jsfiddle so it was erroring out. So no more issues?

Comment: No more issues it's all fixed thanks so much!